# How do i make something happen at the end of x amount of loops in php from a mysql select?

Tags: php, while-loop

X isn't always the same by the way. anyway...

When i am creating a data table with results from database table and the results have multiple groupings of different amounts, I can't figure out how to create an extra row at the end of each group. I can only create it after the new group began. for example...

Let's say i am listing car makes, models, and years, like this:

```
count | year | make | model
---------------------------
1     | 2014 | ford | f-150
2     | 2015 | ford | f-150
3     | 2016 | ford | f-150
4     | 2017 | ford | f-150
5     | 2014 | ford | f-250
6     | 2015 | ford | f-250
7     | 2016 | ford | f-250
8     | 2017 | ford | f-250
9     | 2014 | ford | f-350
10    | 2015 | ford | f-350
11    | 2016 | ford | f-350
12    | 2017 | ford | f-350
```

I want to insert extra row at the end of each model like this:

```
count | year | make | model
---------------------------
1     | 2014 | ford | f-150
2     | 2015 | ford | f-150
3     | 2016 | ford | f-150
4     | 2017 | ford | f-150
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
5     | 2014 | ford | f-250
6     | 2015 | ford | f-250
7     | 2016 | ford | f-250
8     | 2017 | ford | f-250
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
9     | 2014 | ford | f-350
10    | 2015 | ford | f-350
11    | 2016 | ford | f-350
12    | 2017 | ford | f-350
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
```

But the best I could do is this:

```
count | year | make | model
---------------------------
1     | 2014 | ford | f-150
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
2     | 2015 | ford | f-150
3     | 2016 | ford | f-150
4     | 2017 | ford | f-150
5     | 2014 | ford | f-250
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
6     | 2015 | ford | f-250
7     | 2016 | ford | f-250
8     | 2017 | ford | f-250
9     | 2014 | ford | f-350
---------------------------
           info
---------------------------
10    | 2015 | ford | f-350
11    | 2016 | ford | f-350
12    | 2017 | ford | f-350
```

And the way I get that to happen is like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT models.*, makes.* 
FROM models 
LEFT JOIN makes 
ON models.make_id=makes.make_id 
ORDER BY makes.make ASC, models.model ASC, models.year ASC");
$x = 1;
$previousmodel = "";
echo "<table><tr><th>Count</th><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    $year = $row['year'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    $model = $row['model'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$year."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$make."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$model."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if ($model !== $previousmodel) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";
    }
    $x++;
    $previousmodel = $model;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: One way is to instead of echoing the data, add it to a multidimensional array, then add the "rows" into that array or as you do it check the $i+1 values and go from there

Comment: Someone else is gonna tell you this too, I'm sure, but you have to stop using PHP's `mysql_` methods. They've been removed from the current version of PHP, so your code will BREAK if you put it on a server that uses PHP7. Look into `mysqli` or `pdo` (which also works with MySQL) instead.

Comment: if i move the extra tr row above the tr in the while and i add && $previousmodel != '', that seems to work except last group, but i can't just add a fake last row because i need to grab info from each group which will go in that extra row after each group.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the `if` statement on top of the while loop's code block and check if it's empty (the very first time `while` is executed) like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT models.*, makes.* 
FROM models 
LEFT JOIN makes 
ON models.make_id=makes.make_id 
ORDER BY makes.make ASC, models.model ASC, models.year ASC");
$x = 1;
$previousmodel = "";
echo "<table><tr><th>Count</th><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    if ($model !== $previousmodel && $previousmodel !== "") {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    $year = $row['year'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    $model = $row['model'];
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$year."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$make."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$model."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
    $previousmodel = $model;
}
echo "</table>";
```

Edit:

as @u_mulder noted the last info row won't be outputted this way, but this is easily fixed by adding `echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";` before the last `echo` (`echo "</table>";`). Final code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT models.*, makes.* 
FROM models 
LEFT JOIN makes 
ON models.make_id=makes.make_id 
ORDER BY makes.make ASC, models.model ASC, models.year ASC");
$x = 1;
$previousmodel = "";
echo "<table><tr><th>Count</th><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    if ($model !== $previousmodel && $previousmodel !== "") {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    $year = $row['year'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    $model = $row['model'];
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$year."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$make."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$model."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
    $previousmodel = $model;
}
echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr></table>";
```

Btw don't use double quotes if you don't need them.

Comment: It is obvious that in your case there will be __no__  `info` row after last element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $model = $row['model'];

    if ($model !== $previousmodel) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    $year = $row['year'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$year."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$make."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$model."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
    $previousmodel = $model;
```

this should be better;

Comment: It is obvious that in your case there will be __no__ `info` row after last element.

Comment: oh my bad, didn't see the last info ;) will remove that answer as it doesn't match the question ;) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only way i could solve is to create an inner query in the while loop which counts the amount of models. then create a 2nd count variable which starts over after each model group, then echo the extra row if inner num_rows count of the inner query equals the secondary counter variable. Like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT models.*, makes.* 
FROM models 
LEFT JOIN makes 
ON models.make_id=makes.make_id 
ORDER BY makes.make ASC, models.model ASC, models.year ASC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$x = 1;
$count = 1;
$previousmodel = "";
echo "<table><tr><th>Count</th><th>Year</th><th>Make</th><th>Model</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {
    $year = $row['year'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    $model = $row['model'];
    $innerquery = mysql_query("SELECT models.*, makes.* 
    FROM models 
    LEFT JOIN makes ON models.make_id=makes.make_id 
    WHERE makes.make = BINARY '".$make."' AND models.model = BINARY '".$model."'");
    $innernum_rows = mysql_num_rows($innerquery);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$x."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$year."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$make."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$model."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if ($count == $innernum_rows) {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='4'>info</td></tr>";
        $count = 0;
    }
    $x++;
    $count++;
    $previousmodel = $model;
}
echo "</table>";
```